# How to sort every line by it's occurrence count?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a very large file contain many line of text:

```
aa
bb
cc
aa
cc
dd
dd
cc
cc
dd
```

We can see that `aa` appears for twice, `bb` for once, `cc` for four times and `dd` for three times.

I hope to get those line sort by occurence count:

```
cc
dd
aa
bb
```

Can I do this using bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are couple of more options that can be ran directly on the command line:

```
$ cat file
aa
bb
cc
aa
cc
dd
dd
cc
cc
dd
```

#### Command line tools:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c | sort -nrk2 | awk '$0=$2'
cc
dd
aa
bb
```

#### GNU `awk`:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a) print x}' file
cc
dd
aa
bb
```

#### `perl`:

```
$ perl -lne '$h{$_}++ }{ print $_ for sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h' file
cc
dd
aa
bb
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course! Use the `uniq` tool. It detects and counts lines that look the same, among other things.

Try:

```
cat file | sort | uniq --count
```

The call to `sort` is required because `uniq` only considers *adjacent lines*. `sort` puts all equal lines adjacent, preparing the way for `uniq`.

To sort the results by count, pipe the above command again into `sort -n`.

Answer (score 1):

... or:

```
sort file | uniq -c | sort -r | cut -c9-
```

... assuming the input data is in the file `file`.